# Having trouble building project on eclipse cdt? G++ no found!

Tags: gcc, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I installed Eclipse CDT C/C++ and MinGW. But I cant build hello world program. The following message appears in the console.

> Build of configuration Debug for project 51 **
>
> Internal Builder is used for build               **
>   g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\51.o ..\src\51.cpp
>   Internal Builder: Cannot run program "g++": Launching failed
>   Build error occurred, build is stopped
>   Time consumed: 83  ms.

Can any one point out where the problem lies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

g++ is the C++ compiler. MinGW is a port of the gnu compilers to windows.

Is g++ on your path? Open a cmd window and type g++. Is there a similar error? If yes, find g++.exe, put the directory you find it in, in your path. Restart eclipse and retry. If you don't find it, then you probably need to install the C++ compiler from MinGW.

Comment: It's just the environment PATH variable. It's a little different depending on which version of Windows you're running. Google "How to set path windows" and find your version of windows. You want to add the directory that g++ is in to the list of directories already in the PATH.